# Match arithmetic operators in a string but not negative numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match arithmetic operators in a string while avoiding matching negative numbers.

For example, the string : `"-5.0 + 9.34 - 6.0 * - 2.1 * 3.1 / - 2.0"` would match `+, -, *, *, /,`, leaving the negative numbers unmatched. (even with space after the unary operator)

I've done some research and found this : `((?!^)[+*\/-](\s?-)?)`, but it actually matches `+, -, * -, *, / -`.

I am using ECMAScript regex.

More details : what I am trying to achieve is to split a string at the matches using `string.split` while not removing the separator.

for example : `([+\-*\/%])` does match every operators and doesn't remove them in a `string.split` scenario. But it counts the `-` of negative numbers as a match and so does split the chain here too.

So to recap, a perfect answer would be a regex that I can feed to `string.split` that :

(1). Doesn't match negative numbers even with space(s) between the number and the unary operator.

(2). Doesn't remove the match (separator) in a `string.split` scenario.

Comment: Do you split into the numbers and operators? Like `.split(/(?!^)\s*(?!-\d)([+*\/-])\s*/)`? Or, `split(/(?!^)\s*([+*\/-])(?<![*\/]\s*-(?=\s*\d))\s*/)`?

Comment: Yes I would use split, testing your answer doesn't work with "- 5.0 + 9.34 - 6.0 * - 2.1 * 3.1 - -2.0" as it matches the 2 last "-".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is OK for you to have bigger matches, but in which you would only consider the part that is matched in a capture group, then you could require that an operator must be the first one that follows after a digit:

`\d[^+*\/-]*([+*\/-])`

Here the last character of a match is a binary operator you want to match, and it is put in a capture group.

NB: this does not assume that there cannot be a space between the unary minus and the digits that follow it. So it would also work for "- 9 + 1". And if there are no spaces at all it will not skip the minus in "9-1".

Example in JavaScript:

```js
let s = "(-3 + 8) -7 * - 2"

for (let [_, op] of s.matchAll(/\d[^*\/+-]*([*\/+-])/g))
    console.log(op);

// Or as array
let res = Array.from(s.matchAll(/\d[^*\/+-]*([*\/+-])/g), ([_, op]) => op);
console.log(res);
```

## For use with `split`:

You can use that regular expression with `split`, but you need to move the characters from the "delimiter-match" back to the preceding "non-delimiter" match. You can do this by chaining a `map`:

```js
let s = "-5.0 + 9.34 - 6.0 * -2.1 * 3.1 / --2.0";

let res = s.split(/(\d[^*\/+-]*[*\/+-])/g)
           .map((m, i, a) => i%2 ? m[m.length-1] : m + (a[i+1] || "").slice(0, -1));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Yes I didn't think about spaces, I thing this is the best answer since it deals with spaces too but being a regex noob, I'm wondering if the matches couldn't be the Group 1 itself.
https://regex101.com/r/YBO73O/1

Comment: If your regex  flavour supports the `\K` (keep) syntax, then you get put that just before the final match. But I see you have tagged with `javascript`, so that won't work.

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you will do with the matches. If we see the bigger context we can maybe propose better solutions. Still, I think it is not hard to work with the capture group. See code snippet in my answer.

Comment: I've edited my question. I definitely could work something out with your answer, thx btw.

Comment: You could chain an appropriate `map` to the call of `split`. See last section in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a (positive) lookahead that matches any operator that is immediately followed by a white-space character (`\s` or just a space  )

```
[+\-*\/](?=\s)
```

```js
const input = "-5.0 + 9.34 - 6.0 * -2.1 * 3.1 / -2.0";
const rx = /[+\-*\/](?=\s)/g;

console.log(input.match(rx));
```

Or a negative lookahead that matches any operator that is not immediately followed by a number

```
[+\-*\/](?!\d)
```

```js
const input = "-5.0 + 9.34 - 6.0 * -2.1 * 3.1 / -2.0";
const rx = /[+\-*\/](?!\d)/g;

console.log(input.match(rx));
```

Example for both versions on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4bm9Lhug/

Answer (score 1):

You could try following regex.

```
(?!-\d+)[+*\/-]
```

Details:

- `(?!-\d+)`: we do not get the character minus of negative number
- `[+*/-]`: we get arithmetic operators

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n7GLUf/1)

Comment: What if there are no spaces? like "5-9"?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below regex. This considers spaces, brackets and dots as well.

```
[\d\s)]\s*([+\-*/])\s*[.(\d\-]
```

**Demo**

```js
let input = "-5.0 + 9.34 - 6.0 * - 2.1 * 3.1 / - 2.0"
let output = Array.from(input.matchAll(/[\d\s)]\s*([+\-*\/])\s*[.(\d\-]/g), ([i,o]) => o);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `perl`'s `regex` engine handles it differently, or i'm using the wrong `perl` execution flags, but if I'm interpreting this output correctly, i just wanna quickly point out that :

for malformed inputs like this where it's actually a single negative five (`"-5"`) as the chain of `-'s` and `+'s` mostly cancel each other out :

- ```
  __=' - + - + - 5 '
  ```

> ```
> mawk '$++NF = '"${__}" OFS='\f\r\t' FS='^$' <<< "${__}"
> ```

```
  - + - + - 5 
         -5
```

*+ version info : `This is perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0)`*

> ```
> perl -CS -pe 's/([+\-*\/](?=\s))/{{ \1 }}\f/g' <<< "${__}"
> ```

```
 {{ - }}
         {{ + }}
                 {{ - }}
                         {{ + }}
                                 {{ - }}
                                         5
```

…one of the solutions above would split out 5 numeric operators without associated numbers to their left-hand-side, while also extracting out a positive five (`"+5"`, or simply just `"5"`)